# Java stop non-looping Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

So, I have a non-looping Thread that I want to stop. I searched the internet and did not find a solution without creating a looping Thread. 
The Thread requests information from a web server and displays the results in a JList. It does not loop forever. The reason why I made this function a Thread is because it takes about 1-5 minutes depending on how much information are send from the web server and I want to continue working in the application without it being blocked by the request. The Thread looks like this:

```
public class Search extends Thread implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        requestToWebServer(); //10-20sec
        receiveInformation(); //10-20sec
        handleResponse(); //1-4min
        addDataToJList(); //5sec
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that I do not see any way to stop this Thread from running completely. I don't want to use the deprecated method Thread.stop.

**Edit:**
Complete code in run method:

```
public void run(){  
    try{
        log.info(Languages.getString("SearchFrame.2") + this.query); //$NON-NLS-1$

        String resp = ConnectionUtils.request("http://hdfilme.tv/movie/search?key=" //$NON-NLS-1$
                        + this.query.replaceAll(" ", "+")); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$

        Matcher movie_img_matcher = MOVIE_IMG_PATTERN.matcher(resp);
        Matcher movie_stream_matcher = MOVIE_STREAM_PATTERN.matcher(resp);

        log.info(Languages.getString("SearchFrame.4")); //$NON-NLS-1$

        while (movie_img_matcher.find()) {
            img_src.add(new URL(movie_img_matcher.group(1)));
            names.add(movie_img_matcher.group(2));
        }

        log.info(Languages.getString("SearchFrame.5") + img_src.size() + Languages.getString("SearchFrame.6")); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

        log.info(Languages.getString("SearchFrame.7")); //$NON-NLS-1$

        while (movie_stream_matcher.find() && mov_src.size() < img_src.size()) {
            mov_src.add(new URL(movie_stream_matcher.group(1) + "stream")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        log.info(Languages.getString("SearchFrame.5") + mov_src.size() + Languages.getString("SearchFrame.8")); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        log.info(Languages.getString("SearchFrame.9")); //$NON-NLS-1$

        for (int i = 0; i < mov_src.size(); i++) {

            log.debug(Languages.getString("SearchFrame.10")); //$NON-NLS-1$

            String response = ConnectionUtils.request(mov_src.get(i).toString());
            ConnectionUtils.getLastPage();

            Matcher movie_link_matcher = MOVIE_LINK_PATTERN.matcher(response);

            log.debug(Languages.getString("SearchFrame.11")); //$NON-NLS-1$

            if (movie_link_matcher.find()) {
                res.add(movie_link_matcher.group(2));
                con = getCon(new URL(movie_link_matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\\\/", "/")), "HEAD");

                log.debug(Languages.getString("SearchFrame.12")); //$NON-NLS-1$

                last_modified.add(con.getHeaderField("Last-Modified")); //$NON-NLS-1$
                sizes.add(i, con.getContentLengthLong());
            }

            if(Options.getString("DefaultDownload").equals("0")){
                dirs.add(i, System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Videos"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
            } else {
                dirs.add(i, Options.getString("DefaultDownload"));
            }
        }
        log.debug(Languages.getString("SearchFrame.13")); //$NON-NLS-1$

        for(int i = 0; i < mov_src.size(); i++){
            try{
                model.addElement(new Movie(mov_src.get(i), img_src.get(i), names.get(i), res.get(i), dirs.get(i), last_modified.get(i), sizes.get(i))); 
            } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
                log.info(ex);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception ex){
        log.error(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not check interrupt status between method calls?

Comment: e.g., `if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { return; }`

Comment: This is not the whole code only a short overview of what the code does. The code itself is about 60 lines and it is not possible to check status during http reqests.

Comment: But again, you could check **between** method calls, no?

Comment: `Thread.stop` is **extremely** dangerous - it will cause you more issues than it solves...

Comment: Also `Thread implements Runnable` - `Thread` already `implements Runnable`. Further, don't `extends Thread`.

Comment: We really can't help with just the info provided, in particular without knowing more about `handleResponse`. Basically, various techniques that you see that apply to looping threads apply to at least parts of yours too. 1. You can check a flag (your own flag, the thread's interrupt status, etc). between your method calls. 2. You can have a method on your thread that tells it to stop, which sets the flag and knows how to stop anything that's in progress (like the call to the web server). 3. You definitely have a loop in that last method that can check the flag/interrupt status and bail early.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to insert in your code into each loop iteration and in some other places if you wish a check with method invocation `isInterrupted()` or `interrupted()` and if the thread has been interrupted just return from your thread. In your parent thread you need to invoke `interrupt()` method on the thread that you want to stop. Then next time your child-thread will check if it was interrupted it will know to return. Please read more on mentioned methods in java doc for class [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). The only safe way to kill thread is to ask the Thread itself to stop. Any other way is inherently dangerous. That is why method stop() has been depricated

Comment: To add to the above answer, see the java tutorial about interrupts:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html